# View local website on an Android device

Tags: android, web

Web developer here. I have two devices, a Samsung Galaxy S3 & a Samsung Note 10.1. I have developed a website which is running on PHP and I would like to view my website on these two devices without having to upload it to an online server. My local server is a WAMPSERVER.

I've heard that you could use Wi-Fi and connect to my PC's IP address however my wifi signal is very weak (I use a desktop upstairs, router is downstairs) so I would like a setup that requires me to physically connect my devices to my PC.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: get the `ip` of your device and the `port` on which you are running the server application.  Then just type that on your phone browser after connecting it to the same wi-fi network. like: `http://192.168.0.22:8080/page.php`

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I can't do that! My connection is very slow! To the point that i'll have a 8 out of 10 chance of my phone connecting to the downstairs wifi.

Is it not possible to attach my phone to my PC through a USB cable and emulate the site on my phone?

Comment: You mean to say that your PC can connect to the wi-fi but not your phone.. interesting.. another way would be to disconnect your PC from wi-fi and then setup a local `LAN`, then connect your phone to it and test. Also you could physically move yourself if you want to see how it looks (not very feasible though). Rest I will leave it to others to help you out..

Comment: I guess you could use USB tethering or even bluetooth to establish network connection between your PC and the devices. I wish i knew more about this. But i have seen people tether their PC to the device to access internet via their devices. So, the opposite should be possible too.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare My PC is directly connected to the router by an ethernet port. My PC does not have any wireless compability, like wifi or Bluetooth. That's why I need a way for my PC and phone/tablet to connect physically.